# App just crashes when changing station? - AppDelegate error

Tags: swift

So I am getting the following error code

```
Thread 1: Exception: "-[__NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281e8a1c0"
```

However I have no idea what sent to what instance the error is highlighted on this line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

The only command I ran is the following

```
@objc func playdrn1(sender:UIButton!){
        MusicPlayer.shared.startBackgroundMusic(url: "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8006/stream?uuid=\(uuid ?? "")")
        nowplaying(npurl:"https://api.drn1.com.au/station/DRN1/playing")
    }
```

I have narrowed the error to the nowplaying function.

it seems not to like the fact am looping or something like that

```
   func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
        // Scheduling timer to Call the function "updateCounting" with the interval of 1 seconds
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(self.nowplaying), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

The issue is am not sending npurl info with the self.nowplaying.

```
#selector(self.nowplaying)
```

How can I make  `@objc func nowplaying(npurl:String){` run without resending the npurl?

Comment: The error says the crash is related to `NSTimer`.

Comment: @vadian yes thank you made changes to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature `@objc func nowplaying(npurl:String) {` is wrong. You cannot pass a custom parameter type

A timer action method can have two forms

```
@objc func nowplaying() { ...
```

and

```
@objc func nowplaying(_ timer : Timer) { ...
```

Either pass the string in the `userInfo` dictionary or create a temporary property.

Comment: I went with the second option. However I will look at the first option.